# Operation Not Supported Error Mounting NVME Drive on Arch Install

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, mount, nvme

I'm trying to install Arch on a Dell XPS 15 9560.

I've used `nomodeset` to make the text legible (otherwise it's tiny on the integrated 4k monitor) and `pcie_aspm=off` to stop the slew of pci bus errors as per a suggestion on the device's Arch Wiki page.

However, when I try to mount the drive I get a slew of errors (continuing forever):

`print_req_error: operation not supported error, dev nvme0n1, sector {secnum} flags 9`

Where the `secnum` is gradually increasing, presumably it's going through and trying to do the mount starting at every block but I digress.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried secure erasing the SSD to account for any bugs there but nothing.

---

The `dmesg` log can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/hughesjs/f8bc05fbbf36a8351f4fb0dc4fb9a95e). Please note, I did not include the above kernel flags whilst obtaining this log.

The exact kernel version found using `uname -r` is: `5.1.15-arch1-1-ARCH`. This is the one included in ISO `archlinux-2019.07.01-x86_64.iso`.

The `nvme` command suggested in the comments does not seem to exist on the ISO so I have been unable to ascertain the exact SSD model present in the system at this time. Although the device code listed in the `dmesg` indicates it's probably [this one](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/pci/1c5c%3A1284/).

The output of `journalctl -k -o short-monotonic` is [here](https://gist.github.com/hughesjs/98d8c46565278f4768167185a9f88277).

Comment: It's possible this is a defect in the kernel.  Please can you edit the question to include the exact kernel version or versions you have seen this behaviour on? Thanks for mentioning all the kernel boot options you have added.

Comment: Also the specific model of drive used here. I hope `nvme id-ctrl` will show it, although I'm not familiar with nvme.

Comment: I suspect both of these would have shown up in the kernel log (`dmesg` command) after booting.  We accept big textdumps in questions by linking to https://gist.github.com (it might be best if you create an account there first though, although I am not certain).

Comment: @sourcejedi thanks for taking the time to respond, sorry it took me a while to get back to you. It's been a busy few days. I've edited the question to show as much detail that you requested as I can. Although the `nvme` command doesn't seem to exist on the arch boot iso.

Comment: Again, I personally am not familiar with nvme, I just think it could make a better question if you include this sort of information. Maybe the errors in the dmesg help point towards the root cause. But unfortunately they have flooded the kernel ring-buffer.  If you use `journalctl -k -o short-monotonic`, hopefully you can get the earliest kernel messages as well.

Comment: @sourcejedi I have included the SSD model that I suspect it is based on the hardware ID in `dmesg`. I've now added the output of that `journalctl` command for you.

Comment: If you have network available, you can download the nvme command(even in the ISO). Do `pacman -y`(normally not cool, but it's fine in the ISO) to fetch the package database, then `pacman -S nvme-cli`. These are not persistent for subsequent boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this issue today on my Lenovo Yoga 730 with an ADATA NVMe 512G drive. I had errors when running mkfs.ext4, but it did complete. Once I tried to mount the partition I received the same error as described.

I tried the [May 2019 Arch release](https://archive.archlinux.org/iso/2019.05.02/) and did not have the problem.  Seems the issue was introduced with the June 2019 release. Using the May 2019 ISO, I was able to successfully install Arch on my NVMe drive. The kernel version after install is 5.2.4-arch1-1-ARCH.

Comment: If you do a full system update do the errors reappear and have you reported this as a bug?

Comment: I've not seen any issues so far both my main system (Arch) and laptop are at the same level.  I've done a full system update and it's fine.  I did not report the issue yesterday as I was setting the system up. I did report it this morning.

Comment: And the bounty is yours. That worked! Having issues with `xorg` now but I think it's unrelated. Thanks for your help!